# Generate 4 columns of numbers efficiently with given pattern

Tags: r

I would like to generate a dataframe in R consisting of 4 columns, such as

```
V1  V2  V3  V4
10  10   9   9
10  10   8   9
10  10   7   9
10  10   6   9
10  10   5   9  
 9   9   8   8
 9   9   7   8
 9   9   6   8
 9   9   5   8
 9   9   4   8
 9   9   3   8
 8   8   7   7
```

And so forth until v1 and v2 is 8 (or some integer) less then when it started. Also,  v1 and v2 decrease by 1 after v3 is 5 less than (or again, some arbitrary integer) v1.

Comment: Look into the `rep` function for a start. Something like `df <- data.frame(V1 = rep(10:6, each = 5))`. The rest look like they can be created with transformations based on V1.  You might also look here for advice on making a function based on your parameters. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try a `tidyverse`
First you have to set up the starting conditions for column `V1`

```
values = 10:8
n=5:7
```

Then create the rest

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(V1 = rep(values, n)) %>% 
  arrange(-V1) %>% 
  mutate(V2 = V1) %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  mutate(V3 =(max(V2)-1):(max(V2)-n()),
         V4 = max(V2)-1) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 18 x 4
      V1    V2    V3    V4
   <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1    10    10     9     9
 2    10    10     8     9
 3    10    10     7     9
 4    10    10     6     9
 5    10    10     5     9
 6     9     9     8     8
 7     9     9     7     8
 8     9     9     6     8
 9     9     9     5     8
10     9     9     4     8
11     9     9     3     8
12     8     8     7     7
13     8     8     6     7
14     8     8     5     7
15     8     8     4     7
16     8     8     3     7
17     8     8     2     7
18     8     8     1     7
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the delay but it worked perfectly!